# I am trying to read a csv file using pandas but it fails to recognize it - what could be the issue? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, tkinter

I have been trying to read this csv file using pandas and then transfer it to a dictionary using:

```
pandas.read_csv("/Users/vijayaswani/Downloads/England1\ postcodes.csv ", index_col=1).T.to_dict()
```

but each time I get the error `No such file or directory`

neither does using the name of the file work and nor does using its path even though the file is not deleted or anything.

What could be the issue?

Comment: either the file doesn't actually exist or you've misspelled some component of the path.

Comment: **Never** use any space in file or directory names

Comment: @rioV8: while that's certainly practical advice, spaces in filenames are quite common on Windows and OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra space in the file path.

Have you tried:

```
pandas.read_csv("/Users/vijayaswani/Downloads/England1\ postcodes.csv", index_col=1).T.to_dict()
```

Or

```
pandas.read_csv("/Users/vijayaswani/Downloads/England1 postcodes.csv", index_col=1).T.to_dict()
```

Comment: I had tried the first one but didnt work and didnt consider deleting anything from the path as it was what I copied exactly from the terminal.  The second worked though. thank you!!